# How to synchronise data for fusion in Kalman from multiple sensors with different timestamp information?

Tags: localization, kalman-filter, python, sensor-fusion, gps

I'm using Kalman filter to track the position of a vehicle and receive position data from 2 sensors: A GPS sensor and an Ultrasonic sensor for which I want to implement sensor fusion into the Kalman. However, the data formats between the 2 sensors have different timestamps and hence, I cannot directly consider it together without first synchronising them. Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions as to how this can be implemented in Python?
All suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

The GPS data (GPX file exported from an app) collected gives information about the Latitude, Longitude, Elevation and Timestamp (Format: YYYY-MM-DD HH.MM.SS). The HDF5 data collected from a vehicle (HDF5 Format) gives information about the Vehicle Position X, Vehicle Position Y, and a timestamp that is updated like a counter. (Present in file step_S). I'm able to import the GPS and HDF5 files and read its contents but not able to synchronise them.

GPX file reference in below link:
https://github.com/stevenvandorpe/testdata/blob/master/gps_coordinates/gpx/my_run_001.gpx
HDF5 data:
https://github.com/surishell/Kalman-HDF5/blob/master/TestRoute.hdf5

One idea that I had would be checking the timestamp corresponding to the first non-zero value of X and Y positions of the HDF5 file and setting it as a base index against the timestamp of the first position at which GPS value changes. (Assumption: GPS updates at 1 Hz and the Ultrasonic at 500 ms. Once the index is known, the sensor values can be separated and synchronised by corresponding time step). However, I'm not sure of the implementation and could really use some help from the community.

Code for reading the HDF5 data:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = h5py.File(
    "C:\Users\Suraj\Desktop\TestRoute.hdf5","r")

with f:

    st = f.__getitem__("daste_step_S")
    t = list(zip(*st[()]))
    step_time = t[0]
    step_id = t[1]
    step_map_in_index = t[2]
    step_map_out_index = t[3]
    step_v_pos_x = t[4]
    step_v_pos_y = t[5]
    step_v_pos_angle = t[6]

    print(step_v_pos_x)
    test1 = [t - s for s, t in zip(step_v_pos_x, step_v_pos_x[1:])]
    print(test1)
    ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
    ax.plot3D(step_v_pos_x, step_v_pos_y, step_time, 'gray')
    plt.show()
```

**UPDATE**

Kalman Filter:

I've considered a standard motion model: Constant Velocity (Assuming that acceleration plays no effect on this vehicle's position estimation) and therefore, my states consist of only position and velocity.
<sub>+1</sub> =  + ˙ Δ
 ˙<sub>+1</sub> = ˙

Therefore, the state transition matrix would be (Considering 2D positioning (x,y) with latitude and longitude coordinates):

```
A = [[1.0, 0.0, Δ, 0.0],
     [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, Δ],
     [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
```

Since we only have position measurement data available, we can correspondingly write the measurement matrix as:

```
H = [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
     [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

Code for reading GPS data and implementing Kalman filter for Position tracking

```
import gpxpy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import utm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('test3.gpx') as fh:
    gpx_file = gpxpy.parse(fh)
segment = gpx_file.tracks[0].segments[0]
coords = pd.DataFrame([
    {'lat': p.latitude,
     'lon': p.longitude,
     'ele': p.elevation,
     'time': p.time} for p in segment.points])
coords.head(3)
plt.plot(coords.lon[::18], coords.lat[::18],'ro')
plt.show()
#plt.plot(coords.lon, coords.lat)

def lat_log_posx_posy(coords):

     px, py = [], []
     for i in range(len(coords.lat)):
         dx = utm.from_latlon(coords.lat[i], coords.lon[i])
         px.append(dx[0])
         py.append(dx[1])
     return px, py

def kalman_xy(x, P, measurement, R,
              Q = np.array(np.eye(4))):

    return kalman(x, P, measurement, R, Q,
                  F=np.array([[1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
                              [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                              [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
                              [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]),
                  H=np.array([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                              [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]]))

def kalman(x, P, measurement, R, Q, F, H):

    y = np.array(measurement).T - np.dot(H,x)
    S = H.dot(P).dot(H.T) + R  # residual convariance
    K = np.dot((P.dot(H.T)), np.linalg.pinv(S))
    x = x + K.dot(y)
    I = np.array(np.eye(F.shape[0]))  # identity matrix
    P = np.dot((I - np.dot(K,H)),P)

    # PREDICT x, P
    x = np.dot(F,x)
    P = F.dot(P).dot(F.T) + Q

    return x, P

def demo_kalman_xy():

    px, py = lat_log_posx_posy(coords)
    plt.plot(px[::18], py[::18], 'ro')
    plt.show()

    x = np.array([px[0], py[0], 0.01, 0.01]).T
    P = np.array(np.eye(4))*1000 # initial uncertainty
    result = []
    R = 0.01**2
    for meas in zip(px, py):
        x, P = kalman_xy(x, P, meas, R)
        result.append((x[:2]).tolist())
    kalman_x, kalman_y = zip(*result)
    plt.plot(px[::18], py[::18], 'ro')
    plt.plot(kalman_x, kalman_y, 'g-')
    plt.show()

demo_kalman_xy()
```

Comment: How is the ultrasonic sensor measuring the x and y positions of the the vehicle? Is the vehicle in a fixed box and the ultrasonic sensors are measuring the sides? Can the vehicle rotate? This will get more complicated if the vehicle can change the way it's facing.

Comment: You mention that you are tracking a vehicle. Do you have a model for how the vehicle moves?

Comment: Synchronizing the measurements is not necessary. You can trigger Kalman filter measurement updates whenever the sensor(s) generate a new measurement.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Unfortunately, I do not have a definite answer for all the queries. With regards to the first comment, the position data from ultrasonic sensors is purely made from an assumption after reading the extracted HDF5 data file (Column: Veh_Pos_X and Veh_Pos_Y). We obtained this dataset for the university from an external source and the only information we have is that the data was collected from a test run on public roads and that, there are a collection of 8 ultrasonic sensors present on the vehicle (4 in the front and 4 in the back).

Comment: Yes I do. I will update the question with my current code used for the Kalman filter (Only GPS implemented in this). The vehicle model that I consider is a Constant Velocity model. Have posted another query on Signal Processing site with regards to the parameters that can maybe shed a light on this implementation.
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/60311/kalman-filter-parameter-definition-for-vehicle-position-estimation-in-python?noredirect=1#comment120672_60311

Comment: Okay, that is a good idea! I have a query to that: Do you mean like maintain a measurement list that updates based on the data received from the sensor(s) and correspondingly feed it to the Kalman or should I call a Kalman filter and run it separately for each corresponding measurement point that I receive based on the sensor(s)?

Comment: Kalman filters are generally used online. They are fed the sensor measurements as they are generated. You will be able to recover the vehicle state from measurements from collected data but you will have to feed the measurements to the Kalman filter as if it were running online.

Comment: I think you should start with a much simpler project just so you can get a feel for the Kalman filter and become comfortable with some of the non intuitive aspects. I recommend generating a robot car running on a one dimensional number line. Use a constant velocity model with measurements of position. You can recreate the asynchronous complication here by also incorporating robot car velocity measurements. I think this would be a good first step which would allow you to get a handle on the Kalman filter while avoiding the complications of real data.

Comment: Please consider adding info on how you plan to use the ultrasonic sensors data

Answer (score 1):

Kalman filter consists of two steps: Time Update and Measurement Update. For asynchronous measurement case you will have variable sampling time which you will calculate using timestamp. For each sensor data(should come with a timestamp information) you might calculate the time difference between the last iteration and the current iteration. Then, you will use this time difference into the time update step. After that, measurement update will be performed with the corresponding measurement.

```
For each iteration:
    dt = timestamp - last_time
    TimeUpdate(dt)
    MeasurementUpdate()
    last_time = timestamp
```